# Magento 2: How to get Token via Rest API?

Tags: rest-api, magento2.4, token

Magento 2: I want to get admin or customer token via Rest API. Early I used:

End point POST / rest / <store_code> / V1 / integration / admin(or customer) / token

Headings Content-Type / json app

Payload { "username": "admin", "password": "123123q" }

But now this method doesn't work. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

try below API

Use `Content-Type - application/json`

**Create Customer Token**

```
http://127.0.0.1/rest/store_code/V1/integration/customer/token
```

Body

```
{
  "username": "xyz@gmail.com",
  "password": "xxxxxxx"
}
```

**Create Admin token**

```
http://127.0.0.1/rest/store_code/V1/integration/admin/token
```

Body

```
{
  "username": "admin",
  "password": "xxxxxxx"
}
```

Make sure username and password are correct or not and store code also.

For checking store code go to `store > all stores`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I used a similar method. And it doesn't work, although it worked without problems before. I am guessing that something may have changed in the Magento 2 API. Could you confirm that this method works at the moment?